# Select fields from different tables in SQL without a need of matching fields

Tags: mysql, sql

This is just a random question my friend asked me which I also do not know, yet I wanna know :/

Say I want to get this kind of result:

```
mytable_id      bar
    1        content2
    3        content1
```

from the tables below:

```
mytable

mytable_id            foo
    1              something1
    2              something2
    3              something3


yourtable

yourtable_id          bar
    2001           content1
    2002           content2
    2005           content3
```

Many thanks for the help :)

Comment: So you want to randomly join two table together?

Comment: There is no relation between mytable and yourtable.

Comment: @cularis yes sir it's supposed to be a random result

Comment: @Rasel I believe you can still get it without any relation. I've done that a lot of times. Though I don't know in this case.

Comment: Without relation, but at least you have to have some pattern matching like something1's 1 from mytable will match content1's 1 from yourtable.Not a single match here

Comment: Yep,For random results it is okay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT mytable.mytable_id, yourtable.bar FROM mytable, yourtable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Well, as there is no relation between the two tables, you have to make a cartesian product, order the rows randomly and limit the output to the number of rows you want.

Comment: Wouldnt be * though more mytable.mytable_id and yourtable.bar

Comment: good catch Manatherin, edited to use only the wanted columns

Comment: lol thank you so much mister. I feel dumb -.-

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to struggle with that as it breaks the rules by not having corresponding column names.

You could try to use INNER JOIN and then select the two columns, although you'll receive duplicate entries.

Using UNION would collate the information into one column.

I think a better question would be why would you want to do that in the first place, and then design the database accordingly.

Comment: Well, he already said he wants the connection to be random and that it was not a real requirement.

Comment: you're right. although from the initial question I thought he was trying to pair the columns. reading the follow up comments afterwards makes it clearer. Your answer is the best you'll get in this scenario. +1 for that :) *early morning grabs coffee*